# Issue with key of std::map

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, boost-tuples

Consider the following code. A tuple consisting of integer and **vector of integer** is defined as the key of a map. However, I was surprised that the compiler does not throw any error when inserting or looking for a tuple consisting of integer and **integer** as the key. How can this be, since the second element of the tuple should be of the type  **vector of integer**?

```
std::map <boost::tuple<int, vector<int > >, int> test;
std::map <boost::tuple<int, vector<int > >, int>::iterator test_it;

vector <int> t;
t.push_back(4);

test.insert(make_pair(boost::make_tuple(3, t), 4));

test.insert(make_pair(boost::make_tuple(3, 6), 4));

test_it = test.find(boost::make_tuple(3, 7)); 
if(test_it != test.end()) 
throw " test is passed";
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because the third line from the end contains "tes" instead of "test". Can you post the actual code you're compiling?

Comment: could you add the necessary headers and make this a compilable example? I can't get my version of this to compile so I want to be sure we're trying the same thing. Also, what compiler and boost versions do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in Boost and many C++ standard library implementations. The problem is shared by both `pair` and `tuple`. The simplest code to demonstrate it is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    //compiles
    pair<int,vector<int>> bug1( pair<int,int>(5,6) );

    //compiles
    pair<int,vector<int>> bug2;
    bug2 = pair<int,int>(5,6);
}
```

Clang 4.0 with `libc++` and the other one accepts this, Comeau Online accepts it too. GCC 4.7.1 gives an error.

It must not compile, according to:

> 20.3.2/12
>
> ```
> template<class U, class V> pair(const pair<U, V>& p);
> ```
>
> Remark: This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless const U& is implicitly convertible to first_type and const V& is implicitly convertible to second_type.
>
> 20.3.2/23
>
> ```
> template<class U, class V> pair& operator=(const pair<U, V>& p);
> ```
>
> Requires: `is_assignable<first_type&, const U&>::value` is `true` and `is_assignable<second_type&, const V&>::value` is `true`.

Comment: You still don't need the `operator=` quote, since it's never used. :)

Comment: The key condition is **implicitly** convertible. There's an `explicit` conversion `std::vector<T>::vector(size_t, T = T())`.

Comment: And this is the wording I missed in my response.  (And for some reason, although it now says you answered this an hour ago, your posting wasn't visible to me 5 minutes ago.)  This is from C++11, however; under C++03, his code was required to compile.

Comment: @sam It probably does since according to JamesKanze it was legal in C++03. But you shouldn't use it anymore, because it is now illegal in C++11 and will likely be fixed soon in Boost.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the implicit conversion.  It's not from `int` to
`std::vector<int>`; that wouldn't work, because the constructor involved
there is declared `explicit`, and so cannot be used for implicit
conversions.  The implicit conversion is from `std::pair<int, int>` to
`std::pair<int, std::vector<int> >`.  This uses the constructor derived
from the template: `template <typename U1, typename U2> std::pair(
std::pair<U1, U2> const& )`, which is not implicit.  And the definition
of this constructor is:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
template <typename U1, typename U2>
std::pair<T1, T2>::std::pair( std::pair<U1, U2> const& other )
    : first( other.first )
    , second( other.second )
{
}
```

(This is not exactly how the standard specifies it.  But the
specification in C++03 doesn't allow much else.  In C++11, there's a lot
of extra baggage so that things can be move constructed when possible,
but I think the final effect comes out the the same.)

Note that in this constructor, there is an explicit invocation of the
constructor, rather than an implicit conversion.  So for the implicit
conversion of `pair` to work, it is sufficient that the two types be
explicitly convertible.

Personally, I doubt that this was the original intent.  I suspect, in
fact, that most of the language surrounding `std::pair` was frozen
before `explicit` was added to the language, so there wasn't an issue.
Later, no one thought to revisit the issue.  And in C++11, revisiting it
would have broken backwards compatibility.  So you get some unexpected
conversions.

Note that this isn't the only situation where forwarding causes an
explicit conversion to become implicit.  Consider:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > v2D( 5, 10 );
```

Obviously, `10` is not a `std::vector<int>` (which is what the second
argument should be).  But... in C++03, this matches the constructor
template:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename ForwardIterator>
std::vector( ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end );
```

And the standard has some special language for this:

— the constructor

```
template <class InputIterator>
X(InputIterator f, InputIterator l, const Allocator& a = Allocator())
```

shall have the same effect as:

```
X(static_cast<typename X::size_type>(f),
static_cast<typename X::value_type>(l), a)
```

if InputIterator is an integral type.

And the implicit conversion has become explicit.

(Note that without this special language,

```
std::vector<int> v(10, 42);
```

fails to compile: the intantiation of the template constructor, above,
is an exact match, which is better than `std::vector<int>( size_t, int
)`.  The committee felt that requiring an explicit cast of the first
integer, above, to `size_t` was perhaps asking too much of the users.)

C++11 has changed the wording here significantly, and:

```
std::vector<int, std::vector<int>> v2D( 10, 42 );
```

is no longer legal.

No such changes, at laest that I can see, were applied to the
constructor of `std::pair`.